# where will an array declared like this int[][][] arr = { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }, { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } }; in java get stored?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, stack, heap-memory

generally, in java new keyword is used to make an array but this is also a way to do it so I am curious where would this array be stored in java would it be in a stack or in heap memory

Comment: The syntax allows you to omit `new int[][][]` in this case, but that's really what you're doing: creating a new object. It's on the heap.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni The **variable** may be on the stack, but the **array** is on the heap.

Comment: Array initializer syntax is just syntactic sugar. `int[][][] arr = new int[][][] { ... }` and `int[][][] arr = { ... }` are identical.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the comments:

```
int[][][] arr = { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }, { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } };
```

Is syntactic sugar for

```
int[][][] arr = new int[][][] { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }, { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } };
```

In both cases, the variable `arr` is allocated on the stack (if it is a local variable); but the actual array object which `arr` references is allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Array object always store in the heap memory.

Answer (score 0):

Array is an object so

Variable + pointer goes in stack

Actual value goes in heap

Comment: “Variable + pointer goes in stack” — this makes it sound like there are *two* things on the stack. However, there’s only *one* object on the stack.

Comment: Is actually two entities.

The variable name is stored in memory in the map for the variables inside the context.

That variable, later, has a value associated, which is stored in another word (aka, 32/64 byte block)

So yeah, is both

Comment: That is incredibly misleading, bordering on wrong. *Local variable names* are generally not preserved by the Java compiler. They *can* be made available separately, but then they form part of the debug information. The *stack*, on which the pointer sits, has no variable names. There’s only one object, the memory address itself, stored in a 64 bit word on x64 architectures. Having more than that would be unnecessary and wasteful.

Comment: You are right,  I just checked this out. I might have been mistaken with another language. Sorry

I thought it was

|STACK| VarDict[arr] -> arrInHeapLocation -> ///// |HEAP| arrayValue

But there is no varDict in java it seems. It gets removed in compile time and the only thing left is the arrayValueLocation pointer